# How to access phpmyadmin cloud9 cakephp3?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

Hi people I have a problem developing in cloud9. I followed the steps to configure mysql and phpmyadmin. So when I run the app I do it with the following line: bin/cake server -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8080. The apps run fine, but when a try to access phpmyadmin (https://james-mand-cortana.c9users.io/phpmyadmin/) shows an error:Error: PhpmyadminController could not be found.
But when I run the app by running the index.php file (without bin/cake server -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8080) works fine to access phpmyadmin.

So Basically this is my problem I want to run my application with the line bin / cake server -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8080 and access phpmyadmin without any problem.
Thanks for the help.

Here is an excerpt from the index.php:

```
<?php
 if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);
   $url = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
   $file = DIR . $url['path'];
  if (strpos($url['path'], '..') === false && strpos($url['path'], '.') !== false && is_file($file)) {
   return false;
  }
}

require dirname(DIR) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(DIR) . '/config'));
$server->emit($server->run());
```

Comment: Can you show some of the `index.php`? Does that involve any database connection? I suspect this is not really a programming question. It rather looks like good question for superuser though.

Comment: <?php

if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/' . basename(__FILE__);

    $url = parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $file = __DIR__ . $url['path'];
    if (strpos($url['path'], '..') === false && strpos($url['path'], '.') !== false && is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Application;
use Cake\Http\Server;

$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));
$server->emit($server->run());

Comment: As far as I can see, the `index.php` has nothing to do with the DB. I don't think this is a programming question.